# Inserting 2 insert query records in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

need your expert

when inserting query like this :

```
use tabelmantap
delete from T_CekUser
insert into T_CekUser(T_21SI)
select tbla.MASA
from
(
select * from T_21SI
union
select * from T_21SI
) as tbla
where tbla.THN_DATA = '2014' and tbla.KEY_NPWP = '01.576.555.5-123.000'
insert into T_CekUser(T_23SI)
select tblb.MASA from
(
select * from T_23SI
union
select * from T_23SI
) as tblb
where tblb.THN_DATA = '2014' and tblb.KEY_NPWP = '01.576.555.5-123.000'
```

all that query is in one line/page query in sql server

and i get results like this :

```
T_21SI  |  T_23SI
1           null
2           null
3           null
4           null
null         2
null         3
```

been tired, looking around for answer or solution as i wanna be like this :

```
T_21SI  |  T_23SI
1            2
2            3
3            null
4            null
null         null
null         null
```

all file type are int

i have made insert using select from two tables (using inner join) but result is not being expected

any help would be really appreciated..thanks

Comment: Actually, it looks like you are trying to do a PIVOT
I'm assuming each row has a specific meaning?

Comment: well..the data is month number..yup, its pivot..any idea how to pivot that data not using union

Answer (score 0):

Try using the PIVOT statement details are here. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx